# contenteditable="true" not working on a button element

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following button

```
<button data-shq-name="Submit Button" data-shq-id="submit-text" type="submit" data-shq-type="editable-text" class="btn">Get Instant Access</button>
```

Onclick of this button I am adding contenteditable="true" with jquery. The attribute is getting added fine, but contenteditable is not working.
If I already place this attribute in the button tag then it works.

I want it to work when we click on the button and the text becomes editable so that I can save the edited text.

I am doing jquery stuff like this

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("contenteditable", true);
});
```

Any Help Please.

Comment: How exactly would a button element be editable ?

Comment: That has to be for div elems.

Comment: I want to edit the text of the button. For example I want to change "Get Instant Access" in the following button by using content editable true.

Comment: Try setting the DOM property instead of the HTML attribute: `this.contentEditable = true;` or `$(this).prop("contentEditable", true);`. Setting the attribute to the string `"true"`may also work: `$(this).attr("contenteditable", "true");`.

Comment: @Yunus you can use `.val()` or `.text()` for this.

Comment: Even though it's weird it does work with Chrome 36.. somewhat

Comment: @Fediric Hamidi, the code is working only in Chrome as said by Spokey.. Not in Firefox..

Comment: @Yunus, indeed, looks like a Firefox issue. It apparently only honors `contentEditable` on buttons if the attribute is present from the start.

Comment: @Federic Hamidi, its true that it works only if that attribute is already present. For now I will place that by default in button tag. But as soon as I find some way I will add that in my code and also post it here. Thanks Frederic..

Answer (score 0):

This code work in `chrome browser'

```
        <button type="button" contenteditable="true">
            A button
        </button>
```

But for this `type="submit"` works too, but then, the action `submit` is called. Thus you should prevent the second action with `javascript code`...

```
    <form method="POST" action="#">
        <button type="submit" contenteditable="true">
            A button
        </button>
    </form>
```

--

```
     $(function() {
        $('button').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Comment: I already added event.preventDefault but it is not working.. Also the attribute must not be already present in the button as you have in the code above..

Comment: Which browser are you on? My `Chrome` is working well even when attribute is added by `JQuery`. Try adding `return false` at the end of the callback

Comment: @ Salathiel Genese I am trying in FF, Chrome, Safari.. I added contenteditable="true" by default in my code for now.. Later on I will change that if I find some other way to do that. Thanks..

Comment: Did found solution with `return false`?